# Calling command in a package

Tags: package-writing

I have the style file below.

```
\ProvidesPackage{pcuna}[2023/08/13]

\ExplSyntaxOn

\RequirePackage{geometry}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \pcuna:n
  {
    \str_case:nn {#1}
      {
        {migm}
          { \geometry { paperwidth=13cm, paperheight=21cm,
                         left=8mm, right=8mm, top=8mm, bottom=8mm,
                          includehead, includefoot } }
  }


\NewDocumentCommand {\Cuna} { O{migm} }
  {
    \str_case:nnF {#1}
      {
        {migm}  { \pcuna:n {migm} }
      }
        {
          \pcuna:n {migm}  % 13x21 cm

          \directlua
            {
              texio.write("\string\n")
              texio.write("\pcuna:n")
              texio.write("~ Unsupported ~ Argument ~ #1")
              texio.write("\string\n")
            }
        }

  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

But when I use it

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}

\usepackage {cuna}

\title{A Minimal Working Example}

\Cuna {migm}  % Gives error "Missing \begin{document}"

\begin{document}

\Cuna {migm}  % Gives error "Can be used only in preamble"

\end{document}
```

Comment: You've defined `\Cuna` with an optional argument but used a braced one, hence the first error. The second is because `\geometry` can't be used in the body: see the `geometry` docs for details (you want `\newgeometry` in the body).

Comment: The change you suggest fixed the problem.  Would you suggest keeping the code as is and calling `\Cuna` in the preamble, or using `\newgeometry` in the body.

Comment: only change the page setup in the preamble unless you really have special requirements requiring a change mid-document

Comment: but also I don't see why you make this have an optional argument, why not set your default page size and  let the user call `\Cuna` with a mandatory argument if they need a different one.

Comment: I let the user decide upon the page layout form the document class.  And call `\Cuna` to change it.  In the actual code, I have several geometries besides `migm`.